# Kubernetes deployment vs rolling-update

Tags: cluster-computing, kubernetes

I have tried all the basics of Kubernetes and if you want to update your application all you can use `kubectl rolling-update` to update the pods one by one without downtime. Now, I have read the kubernetes documentation again and I have found a new feature called `Deployment` on version `v1beta1`. I am confused since I there is a line on the Deployment docs:

> Next time we want to update pods, we can just update the deployment again.

Isn't this the role for `rolling-update`? Any inputs would be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Deployment is an Object that lets you define a declarative deploy.
It encapsulates

- DeploymentStatus object, that is in charge of managing the number of replicas and its state.
- DeploymentSpec object, which holds number of replicas, templateSpec , Selectors, and some other data that deal with deployment behaviour.

You can get a glimpse of actual code here:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/5516b8684f69bbe9f4688b892194864c6b6d7c08/pkg/apis/extensions/v1beta1/types.go#L223-L253

You will mostly use Deployments to deploy services/applications, in a **declarative** manner.

If you want to modify your deployment, update the yaml/json you used without changing the metadata.

In contrast, kubectl rolling-update isn't declarative, no yaml/json involved, and needs an existing replication controller.

Comment: So if you need to update your pod kubectl rolling-update is still the best choice?

Answer (score 1):

I have been testing rolling update of a service using both replication controller and declarative deployment objects. I found using rc there appears to be no downtime from a client perspective. But when the Deployment is doing a rolling update, the client gets some errors for a while until the update stabilizes.

This is with kubernetes 1.2.1

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that "kubectl rolling-update" is client-driven rolling update, whereas the Deployment object gives you server-side rolling update.

Comment: So which is more preferable to use on production?